# gmaps4rails on jQueryMobile map not showing when redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, gmaps4rails

I am using gmap4rails on jQueryMobile but the map is not showing when I'm doing a redirecting to the page showing the map. The map shows normally when I refresh the map page, but not when I redirect to the page showing the page. Does anyone have an idea why? Thanks! Below is the code

/app/views/items/map.html.erb

```
<div data-role="header">
  <h1>Market</h1>
  <%= link_to 'Sell/Buy', new_item_path, "data-icon" => "plus", "class" => "ui-btn-right" %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', root_path, "class" => "ui-btn-left" %>

</div>
<div class="center-wrapper">
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="/market" data-role="button">List</a>
  <a href="/map" data-role="button">Map</a>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">

    <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>

</div>
```

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>


</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <%= yield %>
  <%= yield :scripts %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/config/routes.rb

```
ProjectZ::Application.routes.draw do

  ...
  match '/map', to: 'items#map'
end
```